# How to generate a script to drop role members on all SQL Server databases?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2014...

I'm trying to run a script to generate another script so I can execute the SQL Server's stored procedure `sp_droprolemember`. I want to run the below query on all databases:

```
SELECT 
    user_name([member_principal_id]) as [Username], 
    User_Name([role_principal_id]) as [Role],
    'EXEC sp_droprolemember N'''+ User_Name([role_principal_id]) +''', N''' + user_name([member_principal_id]) +''''
FROM 
    sys.database_role_members
WHERE 
    User_Name([role_principal_id]) = 'db_datareader'
```

I know about the `sp_MSforeachdb` but I'm having trouble to make it works with the query... (God! How I hate the T-SQL way to concatenate strings!)

Can anyone help me with the right way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this....

```
Declare @Sql Nvarchar(max), @DBUser SYSNAME;

Declare Cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR

Select user_name([member_principal_id])
from sys.database_principals p
INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members r ON p.principal_id = r.member_principal_id 
WHERE p.type_desc IN ('SQL_USER', 'WINDOWS_USER')
AND p.name NOT IN ('dbo','guest','INFORMATION_SCHEMA','sys')
AND User_Name([role_principal_id]) = 'db_datareader'

OPEN Cur

  FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @DBUser

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
 BEGIN
    SET @Sql = N'EXEC sp_droprolemember N''db_datareader'' , @DBUser'

    Exec sp_executesql @Sql ,N'@DBUser SYSNAME' , @DBUser

  FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @DBUser
 END

CLOSE Cur 
DEALLOCATE Cur;
```

Comment: Hi M. Ali! How are you? I want the output of the script like the output of my original script... I really don't want to execute the `sp_droprolemember` automatically...